# I want to let the user know if the delete statement was successful or not is there a way to do this?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Here I have my method that deletes the customer given the id. It works, but if you give it an invalid id nothing happens and I want to tell the user that the delete failed. I tried using an if statement with executeQuery(), but I realized it returns false even if the delete was successful not just when there are no rows affected.

```
private static final String DELETE = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer_id = ?";

public void deleteByID(int id) {
        try(PreparedStatement ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(DELETE)) {
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ps.execute();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already did that and it didn't help

Comment: @tgdavies It doesn't actually, at least not by itself, and it's the wrong method to use anyway.

Comment: @user207421 true, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) which will return number of rows affected. If the return value is < 1, no rows were deleted. Based on that you can show the error to the user.